# Возможно ли использование Gifsicle в Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Есть софт, который отлично справляется со сжатием `GIF` файлов, но у него нет порта для `Android`:

```
https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle
```

Вопросы такие:

- сложно ли подобное портировать?
- И нужно ли вообще?

Если я правильно понимаю, набор из `.c` и `.h` файлов можно преобразовать в библиотеку `C` и подключить ее по `NDK`.

Или тут не все так просто?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключил исходники gifsicle к NDK в своем проекте, если кому-то будет надо, можете посмотреть https://github.com/diskree/7TVEmotesToDiscord

Возможно в будущем вынесу это в отдельный репо, если разберусь и найду время